# BreezeJS get itemcount of a navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, odata, breeze

How to return the count of a 1 to many navigation property?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524073/handling-calculated-properties-with-breezejs-and-web-api) doesn't work. (On client i get value 0).

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336823/breezejs-navigation-property-count) is not bad:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<object> AccountsSummary()
{
    return from t in _contextProvider.Context.Accounts
        select
            new
            {
                t,
                ContactsCount = t.Contacts.Count()
            };
}
```

But i think this will disable the odata capabilities to filter from client-side?

Thanks

Felix

Comment: Do you want the total count of all contacts that have a parent account assigned, or do you want to find out how many contacts a single account has?

Comment: I want the latter (the count of contacts per account)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of an objects 1:n navigational property you can use simple linq:

```
[HttpGet]
public int AccountContactCount(int accountId)
{
    return _contextProvider.Context.Accounts.Where(p => p.Id == accountId).Select(p => p.Contacts).Single().Count();
}
```

Add a nullcheck before this just in case you sent a non existing id or the account has no contacts, but this should work.

Comment: Thanks, that's true but i don't want an extra request (then you need to code it client side + it's an extra request).
With breeze i can get all navigation properties loaded (which would give the count) but for some navigation properties i just want the count, not the actual data..